# Cannot await multiple async method calls in page_loaded event

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `Page_Loaded` event in an UWP application (Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.10). I have made it `async void` so I can call asynchronous methods:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I tried to do this in above event

```
Task s1 = something.MyMethodAsync();
Task s2 = something.MyOtherMethodAsync();
await Task.WaitAll(s1, s2);
```

but am getting **cannot await void** error.

If I re-write it this way it's fine, but I lose some of the benefits of asynchronous calls

```
await something.MyMethodAsync();
await something.MyOtherMethodAsync();
```

Why is `WaitAll` not working?

Comment: `WaitAll` is blocking call

Comment: Task.Waitall() function's return type is void. Hence u cannot perform anything on it. Similarly u can not await also resulting in error. Check the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0#definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1) is a blocking call.
You want [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1).

```
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

Comment: Also as a side note, you should avoid having an async void function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1